# Code obfuscation usage in various languages

Tags: programming-languages, obfuscation

I recently learned about code obfuscation. Its nice thing to do, when you have spare time, but I have different question. Why to do it?

First, there are languages in which I am sure its great thing - interpreted ones, like php, JavaScript and much more. There it seems like a good and more secure thing.

Second, there are languages where this seems to have no real effect for me - all the native code compiled languages. Take C for example. when compiled, all the variable names, function names, most of obfuscation techniques go away. If some can make it into native code, it would be things like recursion instead of for cycles and so, but disassembled code will anyway have instead of names some disassembler-generated identifiers, right?

And last category are languages I am not quite sure about. And that's the main reason I ask. These languages would be Java, C# (.NET),and the last Silverlight used in WP7. I ask because I read some article that state that on WP7 apps, code obfuscation helps preventing code from hacking. But I always thought of byte-code as being very similar to standard assembler codes, therefore again not having any information about real pre-compilation variable names, function names, etc. So, where is the truth?

Comment: The truth is that you don't do it, unless you're bored and into this kind of pastime or are a paranoid who thinks that the whole world will try to steal their super-duper-innovative ideas. And the "security" it brings isn't there, it's a false sense of security similar to the one described by "security through obscurity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it if you want, but don't expect any determined person to be scared away by it. There exist de-obfuscators, people can read obfuscated code as well (just as there are people who can read optimized assembly and reconstruct the original C code). Code obfuscation just gives you a false sense of security and might deter a person who is just curious (instead of deterring those who are serious about stealing your code). All it gives you is a false sense of security but no real one. Schneier aptly names this "security theater".

Yes, many modern languages that retain more information about the source can be obfuscated better than those that are compiled right to machine code. For the latter the compiler already does quite a good job with optimization. Your notion of bytecode being akin to traditional assembler is slightly wrong here, though. Especially .NET bytecode retains enough metadata to reconstruct the original source almost exactly (see Reflector). What isn't retained there are the names of local variables and arguments to methods. But you still need and retain the method and class names.

Another issue you should be aware of: If you give your customers an obfuscated executable and your program crashes, make sure you have a way of getting the real stacktrace back instead of the obfuscated one. Saying "Sorry, I cannot determine the root cause of why my program killed hours of your work since I chose to obfuscate it" isn't going to cut it, I guess :-)

Comment: Well, first thanks. I am more of a "student" than developer. I am mostly interested in HW than SW, and I mostly write in C or assembler from high precision MCU timings. I mostly needed to know ehather there are any real benefits of doing this on bytecoded-compiled platforms. And I must say I am very surprised by your answer, that .net saves metadata to almost reconstruct original source. Why? I always tend to look for logical purpose of things. You know, reading assembly is one thing, but be able to reconstruct code alsmost entirelly is different.

Comment: @B.Gen: Keep in mind that the bytecode is only the first step towards executed code. There is still a just-in-time compiler after that which generates native code. As for why so much metadata is retained, I don't know exactly. But some of it might be for interoperability with other .NET languages, some might be for debugging support (such as marking compiler- or tool-generated code), etc. Reflector is also able to reconstruct the expression trees of LINQ expressions, although in the bytecode only static method calls and lambda functions remain.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscation is a common technique for mobile applications where you have hardware restrictions. Obfuscated code tends to have shorter identifiers and therefore smaller binaries.

Comment: Wait, wat? As already in the question, native compilation strips all the identifiers anyway. Plus, doesn't even come close to answering the question.

Comment: Java is not a native language!